# Capture timestamp in XQuery at different lines

Tags: marklogic

How to capture actual timestamp at different lines of XQuery code in MarkLogic?

If it takes 5 seconds to execute a 6 lines of code, I want to return the actual start time and actual end time of the code execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get a lot more information by using the profiler, but `xdmp:elapsed-time()` will return the exact time it was executed, unlike `fn:current-time()`, which returns the timestamp of the query (that is static throughout a transaction).

Comment: Yes, do NOT try to measure performance by looking at clock time line by line on a functional language because for optimization the system will be executing your code in parallel and lazily and out of order across multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks much. This helps!

Comment: Small note: `xdmp:elapsed-time()` returns a `duration`, e.g. the number of seconds (or fractions of) that have passed since start of evaluating the request..

Comment: To get end time of a query, you'd do `current-time() + xdmp:elapsed-time()`. Be careful of lazy evaluation though, you might need to wrap previous code in `xdmp:eager`, or force execution order by using `let` statements..

Answer (score 4):

To add to what @hunterhacker and @wst have said, you can profile your code in Query Console. Click on the "Profile" tab and click "Run". if you think there is a bottleneck, you might be able to figure things out better this way.